# How to block multiple php requests caused by connection

Tags: php, apache

I have a php that gives points to a user when an action is completed, in this example, when a user scans the QR code of another one.

This is the PHP:

```
$st = $db-> prepare('UPDATE users SET points = points + 50, totalPoints = totalPoints + 50, monthPoints = monthPoints + 50, friendsInvited = friendsInvited + 1 WHERE ID = ?');
$st->bind_param('i', $friendID)
$st->execute();
$st->close();
$db->commit();
```

The problem is that sometimes, the request will be made multiple times (up to 52 in a single user action).
We think it may be because the user has a slow connection or that he's getting disconnected from the internet as our users are using mobile connections.

Is there any way to stop a request if it has been made from the same user in the last X seconds or something we can do to only update the database one time even if the request is made multiple times in a short span?

Thank you.

Comment: it would a `WHERE` clause with the `Last Updated date` right?

Comment: @masterFly but we have to create a new field or Mysql have something to know the last update?

Comment: Don't you have access to the MySQL table?

Comment: @masterFly yes I have, in the table is not a last update date field

Comment: So you can add it. 

Make it a `TIMESTAMP` and set the default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and add Attribute `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. 

So it will auto update once you make update to the table.

`ALTER TABLE `<table>` ADD `last_updated_on` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;`

Then, with each update statement you could check the time on that column against the ( current time - 1 min) like so.

Comment: @masterFly ok I will try to do this. Thanks

Comment: Yes, Give it a try. It should work. Let see what difficulties you come up with.